# c++ Using PortAudio in Windows with Qt

Tags: qt, mingw, libraries, msys, portaudio

I have managed to compile PortAudio on windows using MSYS. 
this process has created 2 files: libportaudio-2.dll and libportaudio.dll.a

Now i want to link the libraries in QtCreator, but i can not since it requires a .lib file.

If anybody have experience of compiling and using libraries with MSYS under windows, your input is appreciated.

(Note: they are compiled using MindGW compiler. I dont want to compile it with Microsoft Visual Studio, since then i will have to compile QT)

Answer (score 2):

to solve your problem is very simple. Here I report an example of a file. pros who need to use:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = mioTestAudio
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lportaudio.dll   <-------- this is the part you are interested

SOURCES += main.cpp
```