# Portaudio library not working with Qt

Tags: qt, mingw, portaudio

I have successfully installed and used the Portaudio library for real time sound output on Ubuntu, with some C++ code.
But my main project is on Windows under Qt Creator. I have tried to build Portaudio with MinGW which seems to have worked because when I run the example "bin/paex_sine" it outputs a sine, but I can't use it in Qt.

I have linked the library by adding

> LIBS += -LC:/MinGW/lib/ -lportaudio.dll

as advised [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284944/c-using-portaudio-in-windows-with-qt), but I get errors of this type :

> undefined reference to `mingw_initcharmax`        crtexe.c

I also tried to use the flag "--enable-cxx" when running ./configure, but then the make returns the following error :

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwtype:89:11: error: '::iswblank' has not been declared
using ::iswblank;
       ^
```

I don't really know what I did wrong and how I should proceed...

Comment: Please do not use images, if you can paste the text directly into you post. Images gets deleted, text does not.

Comment: And with text, you can search, copy and paste it. You can't really do any of that with images

Comment: Yes, sorry about that! just edited

Comment: You are trying to link dynamic library (dll) and the linker accepts only static ones (most often *.lib).

Comment: Ah I see! When I build the library it creates libportaudio.a , libportaudio.la and libportaudio.dll.a . I tried LIBS += -LC:/MinGW/lib/ -lportaudio but it doesn't work either